# Vue.js Data not Displaying in view i am trying to display todo list which just displaying blank

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my App.vue where i have created the Data for todo list and trying to display all todo array data but nothing is showing i am stuck there and please help me to solve that problem

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ToDo/>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ToDo from './components/ToDo';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    ToDo
  },
  data ()
  {
    return {
      todos: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "TODO 1",
          completed: false
        },
         {
          id: 2,
          title: "TODO 2",
          completed: true
        },
         {
          id: 3,
          title:" TODO 3",
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**This is my ToDo.vue from there i am trying to pass the todo.title to Display the title but not working**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-bind:key="todo.id" v-for="todo in todos" >
            {{todo.title}}

        </div>
</div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    name:"ToDo",
    props: ["todos"]

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting a warning in your console.

You are using a [properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) but not actually send it to the component.

Your template should be like this.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ToDo :todos="todos"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Since you're "todos" is an object you need to send it as Javascript which is the meaning of the `:` before the attribute.

Moreover you should definitely ensure that you are sending an Object to your component by specifying it in the definitions of your props.

```
props: {
    todos: Object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the `todos` into `ToDo` component from the `app` component like

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ToDo :todos=todos/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but its still not working.Can you please check that again?